# Append Query String From Variable To Every URL

Tags: javascript, append, query-string

I created a query string and appended it to the URL like so:

```
// HTML from index.html
<input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="redirect(this);" id="YES" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
<input type="button" value="No" onclick="redirect(this);" id="NO" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
// JS on index.html
function redirect(e){

    var mapPg = "map.html";
    var qString = "?choice=";
    location.href = mapPg + qString + e.id;

}
```

Beginning on the `map.html` page, I want to take that query string and carry it through to every URL, except the index.html page.

When the user clicks on `price.html` pg, it'll use the query string to call a function that will pull in the data for the "yes" answer. Same thing goes for the "no" answer.

I can't figure out how to append the query string to the URL of every pg on click.

The nav is a JavaScript include that's been pulled in. I've added a class of `qString` to all the`<a>` in the nav in case it would be easier to target them.

Comment: You can't set a cookie or a sessionStorage or localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Is jQuery an option?  If so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").prop("href", function() { return this.href + location.search; })
});
</script>
```

Comment: This answer somewhat worked, but it disabled all `<a>` tags. I used this answer and combined it with @Barmar 's variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to each page:

```
window.addEventHandler("load", function() {
    var match = location.search.match(/\bchoice=([^&]*)/);
    if (!match) {
        return;
    }
    var choice = match[1];
    var navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("qString");
    for (var i = 0; i < navlinks.length; i++) {
        if (navlinks[i].search == '') {
            navlinks[i].search = '?choice=' + choice;
        } else {
            navlinks[i].search += '&choice=' + choice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one didn't work for some reason. I really appreciate your help. I used a combo of your variable and @ShawnJacobson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = mapPg + qString + e.id;
```

the code here needs to be changed. e.getAttribute("id")

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ShawnJacobson and @Barmar . Although the individual answers didn't work properly, I combined a bit of both to arrive at a solution that works.

```
var navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("qString");
    $(navlinks).prop("href", function() { return this.href + location.search; })
```

Shawn's answer somewhat worked but it disabled all the `<a>` tags. Barmar's answer didn't work but after seeing the variable `var navlinks` it gave me an idea of what to do.

I really appreciate your help at arriving at an answer.